# How to display the results brough from column functions using spark/scala like what show() does to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I just started how to use dataframe and column in Spark/Scala. I know if I want to show something on the screen, I can just do like `df.show()` for that. But how can I do this to a column. For example,

```
scala> val dfcol = df.apply("sgan")
dfcol: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = sgan
```

this can find a column called "sgan" from the dataframe df then give it to dfcol, so dfcol is a column. Then, if I do

```
scala> abs(dfcol)
res29: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = abs(sgan)
```

I just got the result shown on the screen like above. How can I show the result of this function on the screen like df.show() does? Or, in other words, how can I know the results of the functions like abs, min and so forth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use a dataframe, `Column` objects are not meant to be investigated this way. You can use `select` to create a dataframe with the column you're interested in, and then use `show()`:

```
df.select(functions.abs(df("sgan"))).show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please also tell me what functions is for here? I tried, it still works like df.select(abs(df("sgan"))).show(). So functions is not necessary?

Comment: oh - it's not necessary if you have `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` imported, you can leave it out.

Comment: Great! Thanks again!